# .gitignore doesn't unignore subdirectory files

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, gitignore

I am trying to ignore the main .idea directory and exclude specific files from it I want to commit to VCS. I've found out that ! in front of the ignore 'un-ignores' the file. This doesn't work in my case. Any idea what I should do?

I've tried

```
.idea/*
!.idea/scopes
!.idea/inspectionProfiles/JSInspection.xml
!.idea/TRIP.iml
!.idea/modules.xml
```

and

```
/.idea/*
!/.idea/scopes
!/.idea/inspectionProfiles/JSInspection.xml
!/.idea/TRIP.iml
!/.idea/modules.xml
```

Comment: I think you need to unignore `!/.idea/inspectionProfiles/`.

Answer (score 0):

Both syntaxes should work fine. I tried the same on Mac and Windows and it works as expected. Does `git status` show correct information? Check if the Refresh button in the Local changes in the IDE helps.

Why do you ignore the entire .idea folder, btw? See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems for the recommended approach

Comment: git status shows changes to .gitignore only but not to .idea/inspectionProfiles/JSInspection.xml (I have made test changes to) which was supposed to be 'excluded' from gitignore. I am excluding whole .idea folder because we have lots of user specific files such as deployment.xml, vcs.xml, dictionaries etc. I don't want to end up excluding them one by one. I'd rather choose what I need.

Comment: Check if there are exclusions on another level (e.g. in $GIT_DIR/info/exclude files) that override the rules you set.

Comment: And BTW deployment.xml and vcs.xm are not user-specific - they store project-wide config and should be the same on all machines - see the above mentioned link

Comment: deployment.xml is, at least in my case as we're storing our own deployment directories which we're working on. I don't want to end up deploying to somebody's directory and messing up whatever they're working on.

Comment: Found it, my $GIT_DIR/info/exclude doesn't exclude any other files...